# Spring MVC and JQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, model-view-controller

I'm developing a web application and i dont really know JQuery (and javascript) but i want to make a button which lists all the users.

So in the GET method i give a list of users to the model:

```
public String Login(@ModelAttribute("login")
        Login login,Model model) {

    List<User> list=userService.listUser();
    for(User iterator:list){
        if(iterator.getPassword().equals(login.getPassword()))
        {
            model.addAttribute("username",iterator.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("lista",list);
            return "login_successfull";
        }
    }
    return "welcome";
}
```

And in the login_successfull.jsp page i want to make a button in JQuery which lists all the users. I know its not a big thing but i'm new to it.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You can print that `lista` variable into a `div` (in your `welcome` view's HTML) and hide it (`style="display:none"`) and have the button show it. It will be easier than doing it by Ajax.

Comment: ok, but how can i pass the lista object to JQuery and write all the Users? (my consultant told me to use JQuery and) i'm interested in the connection between spring and JQuery

Comment: Spring MVC is a bunch of Java classes that will run server-side (and connect to the BD, run calculations) and will, ultimately, generate the HTML for the users. This HTML is the view files. The `login_successful.jsp` is an example of such HTML file. Now, the HTML is displayed on the browser when the user accesses your server's URL. This HTML is displayed statically (that is, it is just "painted"  by the browser on the screen and has nothing dynamic to it). After the initial loading (painting) of the HTML page by the browser, enters **JavaScript**. JavaScript is a script language that...

Comment: ...that runs on the browser, so you can make pages dynamic. **jQuery** is just a library (a framework, a set of commonly-used functions to make your life easier) built on top of JavaScript. So if you want to learn the connection between Spring and jQuery, you first must understand how HTML is "served by the server" (the Spring MVC is at the server) and then how it behaves in the browser, in this case: HTML -> JavaScript -> jQuery.